# Why does print("aA".count("")) print the value 3?

Tags: python, string

I was working with the .count method for Strings.
The count method finds the total number of occurrences of the argument inside the calling string.

But I don't understand how `.count("")` works. 
Can someone explain that?

Comment: Try `"".count("")`. Now try `"a".count("")`. Now try `"aa".count("")`. Now try `"aaa".count("")`. Now try `"aaaa".count("")`.

Answer (score 1):

There are three offsets – distances from the start of the string – where you can find an empty string: 0, 1, and 2.

```
| a | A |
^0  ^   ^
    |1  |
        |2
```

You can find an empty string at any offset for any string, of course, so `s.count("")` is always `len(s) + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

The empty string occurs three times in "aA": once before the "a", once between the "a" and the "A" and once after the "A".